# JS mouse trigger bad

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, mouse, mouseover

I have a problem with some hover mouse events using javascript. When I pass over one of the entries the reference image is shown but the event is alternate. How fix it? I want to display the current image in "hover" and hide it when it's over the box without alterations.

I try set an interval, stop propagation...

HTML CODE:

```
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <div class="hover_collaborazioni">
                    <span class="home_collaboration-hover"><?php the_field('nome')?></span>
                    <span class="text-16"><?php the_field('anno')?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal z-index-100">
                    <div class="modal-contenuto">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS CODE:

```
let linkModal = document.querySelectorAll(".home_collaboration-hover");
  linkModal.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
      item.parentElement.parentNode.querySelector(".modal").classList.add("d-block");
      item.parentElement.parentNode.querySelector(".modal").classList.add("d-flex");
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
      item.parentElement.parentNode.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("d-block");
      item.parentElement.parentNode.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("d-flex");
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use CSS instead of JS? `.home_collaboration:hover`

Comment: nope, is just a class for future implementations. There is ::before for the little circle before the names.

Comment: "nope" - why not? What does `:before` have to do with it?

Comment: What's the code dump in the comment for? May you edit the question instead and put it there?

Comment: sorry, is an empty class